# Heroku: "bash: ./start.sh: Permission denied"

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, heroku, procfile

I have an app with a Procfile set to run a shell script, but Heroku will not run the script, stating "Permission denied".

Procfile:

```
web: ./start.sh
```

start.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
clear;
until node app.js; do
    echo "Server crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

Heroku log:

> Starting process with command './start.sh'
>   
> bash: ./start.sh: Permission denied
>   
> State changed from starting to crashed
>   
> Process exited with status 126

Comment: What's the file permissions?

Comment: On my local computer? Or on Heroku?

Answer (score 26):

For that to work, `start.sh` must be executable:

```
chmod a+x start.sh
```

If you cannot arrange for that to happen on the machine where the file runs, you can invoke it directly with bash; instead of `./start.sh`, use `bash ./start.sh` (or even just `bash start.sh`)

Comment: I ran this command, and all it did was add a line between sleep 1 and done in the file. I committed and pushed regardless, and no success. Do I need to run this command on Heroku somehow?

Comment: @Nifty255: Yes, the file has to have executable permissions on the machine where it is run.

Comment: Then how do I change the permissions of the file on Heroku? I've done it on my computer, but it seems not to have done much good.

Comment: @Nifty255: I don't know, and it's not really a programming problem. I provided an alternative in an edit; you might want to ask the "how to change permissions on Heroku" question on, for example, http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/heroku

Comment: I can't find your question "how to change permissions on Heroku" on servefault... What exactly was your workaround?

Comment: @AamirMulla: I didn't answer a question on "how to change permissions on Heroku". I suggested that OP ask that particular question on that particular community, where it might be possible that someone knowledgeable would answer (that is, not me). What I did do was edit my answer; you can see the modification by clicking on the link which says [edited Feb 14 '15 at 4:46](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28512490/revisions). (I added the final paragraph to my answer: "Use `bash  start.sh`"). If you want a better answer, I suggest you ask the question on serverfault.com :-)